# Laravel Session not saved by using an iFrame

Tags: php, laravel, session, iframe, session-cookies

I have included an iFrame in my parent site. The iFrame is a Laravel Application which stores some data in session, for example:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    Session::put('sessionIsActive', true);
    Session::save();

    return redirect('/#/start');
});
```

After setting the session I perform a `redirect()` to a route set with `VueRouter`.

I have included the `StartSession` middleware in my `Kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
];
```

When I open the application (child site) directly the session is saved accordingly. But as soon as I try to load it as an iFrame the Session variables are not getting saved.

**Important note**:  On Chrome and Firefox (desktop) everything is working fine and the session is saved. But the issue occurs with Safari (desktop and mobile) and Chrome (mobile).

I do not get any errors in the console so it's hard to determine the issue. But somehow I think the Cookie can't be set correctly sometimes/on specific browser/device constellations.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your idea. But you can check the cookies in the application tab from development tools. For do this, you must be installed Chrome-beta.

The link of the Chrome-beta: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta&hl=en

Comment: You don't have to have Chrome betas to use the developer tools.

Comment: No, I haven't. But I can install it.

Comment: @Kiani In Safari the cookie is not set... As mentioned on Chrome desktop it's working. I dont know how to check it on mobile. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: I think you have a problem with the server-side. Because I checked some websites that they are working with the cookie and they are working on android chrome correctly.

Comment: @Kiani Did you check in with an iFrame?

Comment: No, I not found a website with the iframe. Can you guide me to check a website with the Iframe and cookie?